# dir_util.copy_tree fails after shutil.rmtree

Tags: python

I'm trying to copy a folder to another one after it has been deleted:

```
for i in range(0,3):
   try:
      dir_util.remove_tree("D:/test2")
 #     shutil.rmtree("D:/test2")
      print "removed"
   except: pass

   dir_util.copy_tree("D:/test1", "D:/test2")

   print i
```

D:/test1 contains one empty file called test_file.
If I use dir_util.remove_tree it works fine, but after shutil.rmtree it works only once, on second iteration it fails. Output:

```
removed
0
removed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 53, in <module>
    dir_util.copy_tree("D:/test1", "D:/test2")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dir_util.py", line 163, in copy_tree
    dry_run=dry_run)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\file_util.py", line 148, in copy_file
    _copy_file_contents(src, dst)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\file_util.py", line 44, in _copy_file_contents
    fdst = open(dst, 'wb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:/test2\\test_file'
```

It is more convenient for me to use shutil.rmtree because it allows error handling for removing read-only files.
What is the difference between dir_util.remove_tree and shutil.rmtree? Why doesn't copy_tree work after rmtree second time?

I'm running Python 2.7.2 on Windows 7

Comment: It does work under Linux with python 2.7.2. It seems that for you the filesystem is not synced/flushed in between the calls.

Comment: I also find that it works with win7: py2.7.1 and py3.2.1. Are you writing to a normal disk?

Comment: @JohanLundberg, yes, it's a normal hdd

Answer (score 33):

Seems to be a bug in distutils. If you copy folder, then remove it, then copy again it will fail, because it caches all the created dirs. To workaround you can clear _path_created before copy:

```
distutils.dir_util._path_created = {}
distutils.dir_util.copy_tree(src, dst)
```

Comment: I ran into the same problem and this workaround seems to 'fix' it. But it makes the code look a bit obscure, so I will try to use another copy mechanism ...

Comment: @DikobrAz, Thank you so much~

Comment: Just hit this bug. Thanks!

Comment: I'm here in the future. These are dark times, but this was very helpful. Send help!

Comment: Thank you so much ! :) I have been stucked on this haha

Comment: Thank you so much I have been stucked on this.

Answer (score 4):

Please read the documentation about distutil, this module is for "Building and installing Python modules" (https://docs.python.org/2/library/distutils.html)

If you want to copy a directory tree from one place to another you should take a look on shutil.copytree https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a lack of consistency in the paths separator. 
In Windows you should use "\\" (it needs to be escaped). *Nix systems use /.

You can use:
os.path.join("D:\\test2", "test_file") to make it OS independent. 
[More info](http://www.diveintopython.net/file_handling/os_module.html)

Answer (score 0):

It looks very much like you are getting bitten by the variations of path separators. The main clue is:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:/test2\\test_file'
```

Which concatenates the filename with the directory name using os.sep.  I think you should use the proper path separators if you can.

Answer (score 0):

`shutil.copytree` works!

```
if os.path.exists(dest):
    shutil.rmtree(dest)
shutil.copytree(src, dest)
```